# 1 dimensional representation of congruence subgroups

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Take a congruence subgroup of $\Gamma \subset PSL_{2}(Z)$ and a representation, $\rho:\Gamma \rightarrow C^{\times}$. I was wondering if it's true that some power of $\rho$ is trivial, i.e. $\rho^{N} = 1$ for $N$ large enough?

Comment: There is a subgroup in $PSL_2(Z)$ of finite index isomorphic to $F_2$, the free group of two elements.  

Comment: /is this a congruence group?

Comment: You just need a torsion-free congruence-subgroup $Γ=\Gamma(N)$ in $PSL(2,Z)$, it is then automatically free. In fact, for every $N\ge 2$,  the congruence subgroup $\Gamma(N)$ is torsion-free.